# Hovering over a child of a button doesn't trigger it's hover state in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, mouseover

I encountered a problem that if div is inside button, it will not react to mouse events in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

Is there an easy way to change this behavior, so it acts the same as it does it Chrome? https://jsfiddle.net/JJDacan/trvv7t8e/4/

```css
.ButtonTest
{
 background-color:green;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

.ButtonTest:hover
{
 background-color: red;
}

.DivTest
{
 color: green;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black
}

.DivTest:hover
{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="ButtonTest">
 <div class="DivTest"> Hover over me! </div>
</button>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the div inside the button?

Comment: I think the browser doesn't think it's necessary to have these events on child elements where the parent already handles the same events. But since the div is positioned absolutely anyway, can't you just move it out of the button?

Comment: It will be a custom button explanation. It's visibility is tied with a button.

Comment: So the best way to mitigate this is to have a wrapper around a button and the div element?

Comment: If you put the div right before the button in the source, you can use `.DivTest:hover + .ButtonTest` to address the button when the user is hovering the div.

Comment: Just for record - It's fine on Windows8/IE11